# How can i implement stickers in to quickblox iOS code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

I am integrating Stickers to my chatviewcontroller .

But am not able to understand how can i take it forward , There is some code snippet provided on Quickblox documentation but confused where to place the code and how to handle stickers .`enter code here`

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Stickers

```
1 . pod "StickerPipe" - Done
2 . [STKStickersManager initWitApiKey:@"API_KEY"]; - Done
3. if ([STKStickersManager isStickerMessage:message]) {
[self.stickerImageView stk_setStickerWithMessage:message placeholder:nil placeholderColor:nil progress:nil completion:nil];
}
```

Is this the code i need to write for Input textview on chat . And how

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) STKStickerController *stickerController;
self.inputTextView.inputView = self.stickerController.stickersView;
[self reloadStickersInputViews];
```

Wrote the property , but not sure how to handle the sticker

5 .

```
- (void)stickerController:(STKStickerController *)stickerController didSelectStickerWithMessage:(NSString *)message {

//Send sticker message
}
```

What would be the code inside the delegate .

Please suggest .

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I have same problem, How to implement StrikerPipe SDK in iOS QuickBlox Application. Do you get the solution?

Comment: Currently i do not have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add sticker by following steps, I have added for outgoing similarly we can add for incoming also

i)Create a cell called QMChatStickerOutGoingCell and has imageView property say stickerImageView

ii)ChatViewController (Subclass of QMChatViewController)need to know cell type for QMChatStickerOutGoingCell so we can execute like below

```
- (Class)viewClassForItem:(QBChatMessage *)item {
if ([STKStickersManager isStickerMessage: item.text]) {
        return [QMChatStickerOutGoingCell class];
    }
//Add condition for other cells

}
```

iii)Update the sticker

```
- (void)collectionView:(QMChatCollectionView *)collectionView 
configureCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath{
[super collectionView:collectionView configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

QMChatCell *chatCell = (QMChatCell *)cell;

// subscribing to cell delegate
[chatCell setDelegate:self];

[chatCell containerView].highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];


QBChatMessage *message = [self.chatDataSource messageForIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[QMChatStickerOutGoingCell class]]){
    [chatCell containerView].bgColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [(QMChatStickerOutGoingCell *)chatCell fillWithStickerMessage: message.text downloaded: [self.stickerController isStickerPackDownloaded: message.text]];
}

//Handle for other cells
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user select sticker from `'stickerviewcontroller'`, `didSelectStickerWithMessage` delegate is called. 
 Use this delegate method for recieving sticker messages from sticker view controller and display it with `UIImageView (
UIImageView+Stickers.h)` :-

`- (void)stk_setStickerWithMessage: (NSString*)stickerMessage
                       completion: (STKCompletionBlock)completion;`

I hope you understand above answer and you can ask query for more details.